# How to apply a regex to each sublists of a list?

Tags: python, regex, list, python-2.7, parsing

Let's say I have a list of lists like this:

```
lis_ = [['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t',
         '@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t','Report by @username  - #JeSuisCharlie Movement Leveraged to Distribute DarkComet Malware https://t.co/k9sOEpKjbg\t\t'],
        ['I just became the mayor of Porta Romana on @username! http://4sq.com/9QROVv\t\t', "RT benturner83 Someone's chucking stuff out of the window of an office on tottenham court road #tcr street evacuated http://t.co/heyOhpb1\t\t", "@username Don't use my family surname for your app ???? http://t.co/1yYLXIO9\t\t"]
        ]
```

I would like to remove the links of each sublist, so I tried with this regular expression:

```
new_list = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', tweets, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

I used the `MULTILINE` flag since when I print `list_` it looks like:

```
[]
[]
[]
...
[]
```

The problem with the above aproach is that I got an `TypeError: expected string or buffer` clearly I can not pass like this the sublists to the regex. **How can I apply the above regex to the set of sublists in `list_` ?** in order to get something like this (i.e. the sublists without any type of link):

```
[['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t',
         '@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t','Report by @username  - #JeSuisCharlie Movement Leveraged to Distribute DarkComet Malware'],
        ['I just became the mayor of Porta Romana on @username! \t\t', "RT benturner83 Someone's chucking stuff out of the window of an office on tottenham court road #tcr street evacuated \t\t", "@username Don't use my family surname for your app ????\t\t"]
        ]
```

Does this can be done with a map or is there any other efficient aproach?.

**Thanks in advance guys**

Comment: You should fix your `list_` example since right now it's not valid Python so it's quite hard to know exactly what it is. I'm guessing it's a list containing lists of strings, but we shouldn't have to guess things like that.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\b` instead of start of the line anchor.

```
>>> lis_ = [['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t',
         '@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t','Report by @username  - #JeSuisCharlie Movement Leveraged to Distribute DarkComet Malware https://t.co/k9sOEpKjbg\t\t'],
        ['I just became the mayor of Porta Romana on @username! http://4sq.com/9QROVv\t\t', "RT benturner83 Someone's chucking stuff out of the window of an office on tottenham court road #tcr street evacuated http://t.co/heyOhpb1\t\t", "@username Don't use my family surname for your app ???? http://t.co/1yYLXIO9\t\t"]
        ]
>>> [[re.sub(r'\bhttps?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', i)] for x in lis_ for i in x]
[['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t'], ['@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t'], ['Report by @username  - #JeSuisCharlie Movement Leveraged to Distribute DarkComet Malware '], ['I just became the mayor of Porta Romana on @username! '], ["RT benturner83 Someone's chucking stuff out of the window of an office on tottenham court road #tcr street evacuated "], ["@username Don't use my family surname for your app ???? "]]
```

OR

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i in lis_:
        m = []
        for j in i:
            m.append(re.sub(r'\bhttps?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', j))
        l.append(m)


>>> l
[['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t', '@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t', 'Report by @username  - #JeSuisCharlie Movement Leveraged to Distribute DarkComet Malware '], ['I just became the mayor of Porta Romana on @username! ', "RT benturner83 Someone's chucking stuff out of the window of an office on tottenham court road #tcr street evacuated ", "@username Don't use my family surname for your app ???? "]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried [this](http://dpaste.com/204B67X) aproach and I got this:`[[], []]`

Comment: It works for me. I gave the exact input you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the help, by the other hand how about if I got the lists like this:`['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t', ' fanns ett utvik med "a stitch". @username\t\t']
['I just ! http://4sq.com/9QROVv\t\t', 'Torino on @username! http://4sq.com/9iydG3\t\t']
...
[another sentence in a list]`. I mean just a buch of lists without being in a list?.

Comment: how you assign bunch of lists to a variable?

Comment: Sure, they must be in a list. I was curious by the way, thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a `list` of `list`s of `string`s.

In that case, you simply need to iterate over these lists the proper way:

```
list_ = [['blablablalba', 'blabalbablbla', 'blablala', 'http://t.co/xSnsnlNyq5'], ['blababllba', 'blabalbla', 'blabalbal'],['http://t.co/xScsklNyq5'], ['blablabla', 'http://t.co/xScsnlNyq3']]

def remove_links(sublist):
    return [s for s in sublist if not re.search(r'https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', s)]

final_list = map(remove_links, list_)
# [['blablablalba', 'blabalbablbla', 'blablala'], ['blababllba', 'blabalbla', 'blabalbal'], [], ['blablabla']]
```

If you want to remove any empty sub-lists afterwards:

```
final_final_list = [l for l in final_list if l]
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The thing is that I have like this the strings of each sublist: [`blablablalba blabalbablbla blablala`] instead of `['blablablalba', 'blabalbablbla',' blablala']` on each sublist I have a large comment.

Comment: `[blablablalba blabalbablbla blablala]` isn't valid python code. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Sorry for using `blabla`, I was trying to explain it in an easy way. I edited

Comment: If you run the code on your new input, it returns `[['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t', '@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t']]` which appears to be correct?

Comment: I got this: `[['"Fun is the enjoyment of pleasure"\t\t', '@username det fanns ett utvik med "sabrina without a stitch". acke nothing. @username\t\t'], []]` in the last sublist it removed everything instead of just remove the links.